# My Ajax syntax seems to be wrong

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm very new to Ajax, and something I thought would be very easy doesn't work. To simplify my issue, I'm trying to substitute a list item saying "Hello" with one saying "Goodbye":

I have html:

```
<ul>
<li>Hello <div class="change">X</div></li>
</ul>
```

A separate php file ('Substitute.php')

```
<?php 
echo "<li>";
echo "Goodbye";
echo "</li>";
?>
```

And in my html file, I'm trying to do a simple Ajax call that I found online:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".change").click(function() {                
$.ajax({url:"Substitute.php", success:function(result){
$(this).parent().html(result); 

}});
});
})    

</script>
```

It doesn't work though. If I get rid of the Ajax and just do $(this).parent().load("Substitute.php"); it works fine. However, my php file is actually much more complicated and links to a MySQL database, so I definitely need to do it through Ajax.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong on the Ajax syntax? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".change").click(function() {
      var element = $(this);                
      $.ajax({url:"Substitute.php", success:function(result){
         element.parent().html(result); 
      }});
   });
})
```

Explanation:
You accessed to $(this) inside a callback function of the ajax call, expecting it to be the DOM element that you want to update. In suggested code we store the DOM element that we want in "element" variable using closure and access it directly from the callback function...

Answer (score 0):

Because in your ajax success function, `this` object not refered to the clicked object. So you need to save the clicked object into a temporary variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".change").click(function() {
        var obj = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: "Substitute.php",
            success: function(result) {
                $(obj).parent().html(result);

            }
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: FWIW, `success` is being deprecated out of the jqXHR object. Better to use `done` (`done: function(result) { ... }`  ). ref: http://devdocs.io/jquery/jquery.ajax

Comment: I think this is basically the same as Vitali's above which works - thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Try to get this in an another object and use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith) instead of [html](http://api.jquery.com/html) as you are getting `li` from your `Substitute page`, otherwise your html would not vaild, in your case you will get `li` in another `li` try this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".change").click(function () {
        var $that=$(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "Substitute.php",
            success: function (result) {
                $that.parent().replaceWith(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If you don't want to change your code by `replaceWith` then return text only from your `PHP Page`

Comment: Thanks Rohan - I do actually need the html() for what I'm about to do, but the var $that is what I needed to make it work, and lots of you suggested it. (Not sure I entirely understand the explanation why it was needed, but it works, so thanks!)

Comment: It is needed because the `scope of this` is inside the click event only not in your `ajax success callback function`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have included the jquery file to support ajax. ?
try and alert something on the Click event before you do a ajax call. Like this

```
$(".change").click(function() {
 alert('jQuery Working.!!');
});
```

kindly check if you are getting an alert. 
Lets debug it one by one.

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo - I had ajax elsewhere on my page, so it was working (should have said - sorry). Someone's fixed my problem below though.